# Entity Framework 5 Enums with Description attribute using Database First

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I would like to something like this:

```
public enum States
{
    California,
    [Description("New Mexico")]
    NewMexico,
    [Description("New York")]
    NewYork,
    [Description("South Carolina")]
    SouthCarolina,
    Tennessee,
    Washington
}
```

So that when I'm making a Drop Down List using .NET MVC I can use spaces in my names. If I used Code First then I could do this but I am using Database First and the .edmx designer doesn't allow attributes on the generated states (as far as I know!). Any ideas on how I can do this? I am using .NET 4.5 and EF 5 beta.

Comment: I assume you are pulling the states from a table?  Could you please post the table structure?

Comment: Actually no, you can define the Enum and it's states in the designer without having to have a related table.

Comment: Ok, so you are doing a Data First / Model First hybrid?

Comment: Thanks for looking at this!
I am using the EF DbContext Generator to make my Classes from an EDMX file which I have generated from the DB.

Comment: I worked it out!

You create the Enum in a class. Then you add the Enum to the field in the designer, give it the same name as the one you wrote. Then tick the box that says "Reference External Type" and give it the Namespace+type. Then it will reference yours rather than generating code.

Comment: @mikeydelamonde, how have you done it exactly? I tried the same but it is still generating the enum code, even by using the "Reference External Type" fields...

Answer (score 1):

It's only possible to use external types for enums if you're using `DbContext` based T4 templates. It's not supported for entities that derive from EntityObject or use ObjectContext directly.

- [Microsoft Connect issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio/feedback/details/739409/adding-enum) (closed as 'By design')
- [Blog post](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2012/09/11/using-exisiting-enum-types-in-entity-framework-5/)